# Excel add-in fails with 0x8004063E

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, excel-addins, office-addins

I have an Excel add in which used to work perfectly.
Lately, many customers received the following error (in the end of this question).

Environment details:

- Windows 7/8 64 bit.
- Microsoft Office 2013 64 bit
- Add in is compiled under .net 3.5

Any help will be highly appreciated.

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004063E
>
> ************** Exception Text **************
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004063E): Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004063E
>      at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>      at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, Boolean useFastPath, IntPtr& executor)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IDomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomain(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, IntPtr& executor)

Comment: A very fast google search on your exception brought up this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2022447 Please do some basic research before asking questions here.

Comment: Uncommon error code.  Shooting off the hip, I'd guess your users are moving to Windows 8, .NET 3.5 is not installed by default.

Comment: @ZachSpencer This is not what causing the issue. As you can see - the kb talks about a re-published add-in which had it's target .NET version changed, this is not the case.

Comment: @ZachSpencer Another thing - the kb discusses document-level addin, while i'm talking about application-level addin

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same exception for outlook add-in.

with Environment:

1. Windows 7 64 bit.
   Microsoft outlook 2013 64 bit Add in is compiled
   under .net 4.5 VS 2013

Compiled add-in under .net 4.0 fixed the issue.

Comment: This didn't work for us. It's worth noting that while this problem happens for some users, it doesn't happen for others, and the correct version of .net is installed on each machine

Answer (score 1):

Building with a different .NET framework didn't help for us, and isn't a reliable option anyways since we need .NET 4.5.

Reinstalling Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime made the problem disappear in some instances.  Dancing clockwise around the campfire three times, chanting "vee-store" also sometimes helps, but not all of our customers have campfires.

It seems the use case that fails for us is Windows 7, Office 2010, allow Office to register for updates via Windows Updates, VSTOR is installed via Windows Updates, .NET Framework is installed *after* VSTOR. This is the case where we get this error. Re-installing VSTOR fixes it for us.

Another problem seems to be that our earlier alpha versions used the ClickOnce installation, and later versions used an MSI installer. If the ClickOnce alpha version threw an exception during startup and got itself blacklisted with Excel, it would cause the MSI installation to fail. Searching the registry for our add-in name found extra spots in the HKCU and HKLM which conflicted.