# Excel VSTO add-in cannot be found or loaded

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I am trying to write my first Excel add-in with the Visual Studio Office Developer Tools. I follow this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx. Thus my code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.WorkbookBeforeSave += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(Application_WorkbookBeforeSave);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void Application_WorkbookBeforeSave(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb, bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet);
            Excel.Range firstRow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");
            firstRow.EntireRow.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
            Excel.Range newFirstRow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");
            newFirstRow.Value2 = "This text was added by using code";
        }

        // VSTO-generated code
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the program and Excel starts, Excel issues a message that the add-in could not been found or loaded and the following code:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004063E

****************************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004063E): Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004063E
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, Boolean useFastPath, IntPtr& executor)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IDomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomain(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, IntPtr& executor)
```

I guess that the problem is not in the code but in the way Excel tries to load the add-in. I have checked that all the files that are mentioned [on this Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/388t39t8.aspx) for application-level projects and the registry entries [from this Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) are present. (Interestingly, the registry entries are in the key for 32 bit although I use 64 bit. I tried adding them to the 64 bit key manually but that did not help.) VSTO add-ins are activated in Excel.

The operating system is Windows 7 64 bit with user privileges and I use Excel 2013 and Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389330/excel-add-in-fails-with-0x8004063e. Here might be the solution: https://www.xltoolbox.net/blog/2015/01/troubleshooting-vsto-add-ins-for-office.html.

Comment: What about Office ? 32 bit or 64 ? If it is x64 let check all the dlls your plugin use also check its output architecture (x86 wont work)